# plot p value on scatter plot using statsmodel (pandas/matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statsmodels, p-value

I need help adding p-values onto my figures, but I'm having three issues. 1) Whenever I use `statsmodel` to calculate `p-values`, I get two `p-values`, one for an "intercept" and one for the y-variable (which is the one I want to plot). 2) I am using a loop to create multiple figures at once. 3) I don't know how to isolate the specific `p-value` that I want to plot because when I print the p-values, it shows both of the `p-values` for each figure that I am preparing. Here is my code in case you want to see what I mean about the two `p-values`:

```
###(this is sample data in case you are trying to recreate the code)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm

dpm=pd.DataFrame({'pm10_3135_2018':[30,34,32,44,45,46,59,54,59,30],
'nox_3135(ppb)':[20,29,27,31,33,33,34,23,32,31],
'CO_3135(ppm)':[0.8,0.9,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.3],
'O3_mda8_3135':[42,45,47,51,52,52,57,67,69,70],
'pm25_3135_2018':[6,7,6,7,4,5,2,11,9,18]})

##PM2.5 vs variables - whole year

dpm = dpm.reset_index()

x = [dpm.pm10_3135_2018,dpm['nox_3135(ppb)'],dpm['CO_3135(ppm)'],dpm.O3_mda8_3135]
y = dpm.pm25_3135_2018
xlab = ["PM10 (ug/m^3)", "NOx (ppb)", "CO (ppm)", "O3 MDA8 (ppb)"]
fnames = ['NOMR2_PM10vsPM25_yr_2018.png','NOMR2_NOxvsPM25_yr_2018.png','NOMR2_COvsPM25_yr_2018.png','NOMR2_O3vsPM25_yr_2018.png']

for xcol,lab,fname in zip(x,xlab,fnames):

    correlation_matrix1 = np.corrcoef(xcol, y)
    correlation_xy1 = correlation_matrix1[0,1]
    R2_1 = correlation_xy1**2
    m, b = np.polyfit(xcol,y,1)
    equation = 'y = ' + str(round(m,4)) + 'x' ' + ' + str(round(b,4))
    R2 = '$R^2$ =' + str(round(R2_1,3))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xcol, y, color='xkcd:red',linestyle='None',marker='o')
    ax.set_xlabel(lab,fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylabel('PM2.5 (ug/m^3)',fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylim(0,)
    ax.set_xlim(0,)
    plt.text(0.75, 0.65, equation, horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center',
             transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.text(0.7, 0.6, R2, horizontalalignment='center',
         verticalalignment='center',
         transform=ax.transAxes)
    model = smf.ols('xcol ~ y', data=dpm).fit()
    print(model.summary())
    print(model.pvalues)
```

For the next part of the code, I have this, but I need a way to call the `y` variable `p-values` from the `statsmodel` function and create a new variable `P` to represent those `p-values`, and then plot `P` on the figure, but I don't know how to do that. **(disclaimer, this is not my actual data so there isn't much of a correlation between the data points, but the process is the same).**

```
plt.text(0.7, 0.55, P, horizontalalignment='center',
     verticalalignment='center',
     transform=ax.transAxes)

fig.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig(fname)
```

Comment: It's subjective, of course, but typically `y` is the dependent variable and `x` is the independent variable so the formula would be `y ~ xcol` whereby you're estimating y = constant + b x + error. I just want to make sure you are estimating what you actually want to be estimating

Comment: Does this help : `P = model.pvalues['y']` and then `plt.text(0.7, 0.55, P...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.pvalues` is a pandas series (ie check with `type(model.pvalues)` so if you want to extract the p-value for `y`, then you simple do

```
model.pvalues['y']
```

To add the p-value to your plot, you can add:

```
print(model.pvalues)
plt.text(0.7, 0.8, "y p-values: %.2f" %(model.pvalues['y']), horizontalalignment='center',
     verticalalignment='center',
     transform=ax.transAxes)
```

where I added a little of text formatting `"y p-value.."` to make it clearer what you're plotting onto the plot.

Here's the full loop:

```
for xcol,lab,fname in zip(x,xlab,fnames):

    correlation_matrix1 = np.corrcoef(xcol, y)
    correlation_xy1 = correlation_matrix1[0,1]
    R2_1 = correlation_xy1**2
    m, b = np.polyfit(xcol,y,1)
    equation = 'y = ' + str(round(m,4)) + 'x' ' + ' + str(round(b,4))
    R2 = '$R^2$ =' + str(round(R2_1,3))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xcol, y, color='xkcd:red',linestyle='None',marker='o')
    ax.set_xlabel(lab,fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylabel('PM2.5 (ug/m^3)',fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylim(0,)
    ax.set_xlim(0,)
    plt.text(0.75, 0.65, equation, horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center',
             transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.text(0.7, 0.6, R2, horizontalalignment='center',
         verticalalignment='center',
         transform=ax.transAxes)
    model = smf.ols('xcol ~ y', data=dpm).fit()
    print(model.summary())
    print(model.pvalues)

    #added code:
    plt.text(0.7, 0.8, "y p-values: %.2f" %(model.pvalues['y']), horizontalalignment='center',
         verticalalignment='center',
         transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Also, if I am interpreting your code, annotations, and standard statistics appropriately then your formula should be

`model = smf.ols('y ~ xcol', data=dpm).fit()`

In this case, you want to be extracting the p-values for the x variable so you modify the above code with `model.pvalues[xcol]`

Comment: thank you! one more thing, this worked but the p value is like 15 decimal places long, is there a way that I can condense it to only 3 decimal places plotted?

Comment: This is where string formatting comes in handy. You should use the annotation I provide in the code. To print to 3 decimal places, you write; `"p-values: %.3f" %(model.pvalues['y'])`. In general, if you want to print a decimals, it's good to use string formatting ie `print("decimal rounded to 4 digits: %.4f" %.02212313)`